# MySql Logic Optimization

Tags: mysql

Currently we have a ticket management system and like all ticketing systems it needs to assign cases in a round-robin manner to the agents. Also, at the same time the agent can apply their own filtering logic and work on their queue.

The problem,

1. The table with the tickets is very large now, spans over 10 million rows.
2. One ticket should never be assigned to two different users.
3. To solve the above problem, this is the flow we have,
4. Select query is fired with filter criteria and limit 0,1
5. The row returned by the above query is then selected based on id and locked for update.
6. Lastly we fire the update saying user X has picked the case.
7. While step 3 executes other user cannot get a lock on the same case, so they fire 3.a query may be multiple times to get the next available case.
8. As number of users increase this time in step 4 goes higher and higher.

We tried doing a select for update in query at step 4 itself, but it makes the entire query slow. Assuming this is because a huge number of rows in the select query.

Questions,

- Is there a different approach we need to take altogether?
- Would doing a select and update in a stored procedure ensure the same results as doing a select for update and then update?

P.S - I have asked the same question stackexchange.

Comment: is it necessary to lock the row. you can also do it without a lock : read a row via SELECT and you get the old user, and at the UPDATE you added the criteria WHERE ... AND user = old_user. so if update one row it all ok else a other process has get this ticket

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to use MySQL level locking to ensure that a ticket cannot be assigned to more than one person. This way there is no way to detect if a ticket is locked by a user.

I would implement an application level lock by adding 2 lock related fields to the tickets table: a timestamp when the lock was applied and a user id field telling you which user holds the lock. The lock related fields may be held in another table (shopping cart, for example can be used for this purpose).

When a user selects a ticket, then you try to update these lock fields with a conditional update statement:

```
update tickets
set lock_time=now(), lock_user=...
where ticket_id=... and lock_time is null
```

Values in place of `...` are supplied by your application. `lock_time is null` criteria is there to make sure that if the ticket has already been selected by another user, then the later user does not override the lock. After the update statement check out the number of rows affected. If it is one, then the current user acquired the lock. If it is 0, then someone else locked the ticket.

If you have the locking data in another table, then place a unique restriction on the ticket id field in that table and use insert to acquire a lock. If the insert succeeds, then the lock is acquired. If it fails, then another user has locked the ticket.

The lock is usually held for a number of minutes, after that your application must release the lock (set locking fields to null or delete the locking record from the other table).